# Check if XML node already exists

Tags: xml, vbscript

I would like to check in my VBScript if an XML node already exists. If this is the case the Node should not be added again, the data should be updated instead. Is there a way I can solve that? Here is my code:
When the script is executed, a new node will be created with the computer data in it. (In the case that a new server or hard disk is added.) Only thing missing is that when the node already exists, it will be updated with more recent data.

Here is my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SERVERSPEICHER>
<SERVER name="LANADMIN">
        <FESTPLATTE id="1" disk="C:">
            <SPEICHER>'450,6'</SPEICHER>
    <FREIERSPEICHER>'356,5'</FREIERSPEICHER>
    </FESTPLATTE><FESTPLATTE id="2" disk="Q:">
        <SPEICHER>'13,7'</SPEICHER>
    <FREIERSPEICHER>'3,4'</FREIERSPEICHER>
        </FESTPLATTE>
    </SERVER>
</SERVERSPEICHER>
```

VBScript:

```vb
on Error Resume Next  

Function GetElementFromXmlString(xmlString)
    Dim doc
    set doc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    doc.async = False
    doc.preserveWhiteSpace= False
    doc.loadXML(xmlString)
    Set GetElementFromXmlString = doc.documentElement
End Function

Dim xmlDoc, nNode, objNodeList, plot
dim serverNodeItem
dim diskNodeItem
dim diskID

y = 1
id = 1

set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputerName = objNetwork.Computername

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &         strComputerName)
Set colDiskSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where  DriveType=3") ' Festplattendaten

Set xmlDOc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load "server.xml"

Set objRoot = xmlDoc.documentElement

If Err.Number = 0 Then  

Dim xmlString
xmlString = "<SERVER name='"& strComputerName &"'>" & _
            "</SERVER>"

Dim newServer
Set newServer = GetElementFromXmlString(xmlString)
objRoot.appendChild(newServer)

Set objServer = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode("//SERVER")

For Each objDisk In colDiskSettings 

    strDiskDeviceID = objDisk.DeviceID 

    strDiskSize = FormatNumber((objDisk.Size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)),1,0,0,0) 

    strDiskFreeSpace = FormatNumber((objDisk.FreeSpace / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)),1,0,0,0)

    Dim xmlDiskString
    xmlDiskString = "<FESTPLATTE id='"& id &"' disk='"& strDiskDeviceID &"'>" & _
                "       <SPEICHER>'"& strDiskSize &"'</SPEICHER>" & _
                "       <FREIERSPEICHER>'"& strDiskFreeSpace &"'</FREIERSPEICHER>" & _
                "   </FESTPLATTE>"

    If y = id Then

        Dim newDisk
        Set newDisk = GetElementFromXmlString(xmlDiskString)

        objServer.appendChild(newDisk)

    End If

    id = id + 1
    y = y + 1 

Next   

Else   
    Err.clear   
End If
strResult = xmldoc.save("server.xml")
```

Any Help would be nice!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a particular node already exists like this:

```vbs
Set nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//SERVER[@name='" & strComputerName & "']")
If nodes.Length = 0 Then
  'add node
Else
  'update existing node
End If
```

Comment: @user3073688 maybe you should mark this as the Accepted Answer so other users with the same question can easily find this answer too. (And to show your appreciation to the answerer by giving him virtual internet points!)

Comment: Sry, i am new to Stackoverflow... I marked it! Thanks for the advise!